# VC++ optimization double loads from one _mm256_loadu_ps intrinsic

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, simd, avx

Here's a source:

```
// Same as multiplyComplex, multiplies 4 numbers    
__forceinline __m256 multiplyComplex_x4( const __m256 x, const __m256 y )
{
    // If the inputs are [ a, b ] and [ c, d ] the formula is [ ac - bd, ad + bc ]
    
    const __m256 x2 = _mm256_movehdup_ps( x );  // [ b, b ]
    const __m256 yRev = _mm256_permute_ps( y, shuffleMask_rev64q );     // [ d, c ]
    const __m256 prod2 = _mm256_mul_ps( x2, yRev ); // [ bd, bc ]
    const __m256 x1 = _mm256_moveldup_ps( x );  // [ a, a ]
    return _mm256_fmaddsub_ps( x1, y, prod2 );
}

// Same as fftMainLoop, handles 4 complex numbers
__forceinline void fftMainLoop_x4( const __m256 omega, complex* a1c, complex* a2c )
{
    const __m256 a1 = _mm256_loadu_ps( (const float*)a1c );
    const __m256 a2 = _mm256_loadu_ps( (const float*)a2c );

    const __m256 product = multiplyComplex_x4( omega, a2 );

    _mm256_storeu_ps( (float*)a1c, _mm256_add_ps( a1, product ) );
    _mm256_storeu_ps( (float*)a2c, _mm256_sub_ps( a1, product ) );
}
```

Here's the assembly made by VC++ 2017, the complete loop that calls that function:

```
00007FF7CC3F11B0  lea         eax,[r8+4]  
00007FF7CC3F11B4  mov         ecx,r8d  
00007FF7CC3F11B7  vpermilps   ymm0,ymmword ptr [rdi+rax*8],0B1h  
00007FF7CC3F11BE  vmulps      ymm2,ymm0,ymm4  
00007FF7CC3F11C2  vfmaddsub231ps ymm2,ymm5,ymmword ptr [rdi+rax*8]  
00007FF7CC3F11C8  vmovups     ymm3,ymmword ptr [rdi+rcx*8]  
00007FF7CC3F11CD  vaddps      ymm0,ymm2,ymm3  
00007FF7CC3F11D1  add         r8d,8  
00007FF7CC3F11D5  vsubps      ymm1,ymm3,ymm2  
00007FF7CC3F11D9  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rdi+rcx*8],ymm0  
00007FF7CC3F11DE  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rdi+rax*8],ymm1  
00007FF7CC3F11E3  cmp         r8d,esi  
00007FF7CC3F11E6  jb          fft_run+1B0h (07FF7CC3F11B0h)
```

The code reads from memory 50% more often than I would like it to.

The two instructions

```
vpermilps   ymm0,ymmword ptr [rdi+rax*8],0B1h
```

and

```
vfmaddsub231ps ymm2,ymm5,ymmword ptr [rdi+rax*8]
```

both access the same memory address.

Is there a way to convince the compiler to emit `vmovups` for my `_mm256_loadu_ps`, instead of trying to merge the load?

Comment: Funny, I just got around to reporting basically the same bug for GCC a couple days ago.  [PR97366, Redundant load with SSE/AVX vector intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97366).  (Of course including some discussion of the perf implications.)  In your case, like mine, this is obviously a loss because the indexed addressing mode means the memory source can't stay micro-fused on Intel CPUs.  It could be saving front-end throughput on Zen / Zen2... But at the cost of more load-port / AGU pressure.

Comment: Generally your options are to play with tuning options until the code changes, write it by hand in asm, or wait for compiler devs to fix the missed optimization.  Since you only use `_mm256_loadu_ps` once on the memory location, this is not your fault.  MSVC generally doesn't optimize intrinsics (unlike better compilers, e.g. clang will look for different shuffles and instructions that implement the same logic, same as optimizing scalar code where `*` doesn't mean an `imul` instruction).  But MSVC does fold loads into memory source operands for other insns, and was too aggressive here.

Comment: Also note that loading the same thing twice from cacheable memory doubles load-port demand, but not *RAM* reads.  The question title kind of gives the impression that MSVC is doing some larger-scale anti-optimization that ends up causing more cache misses.  I think I have a better phrasing...